# getting wrong x y from OnTouchListener

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to draw a circle where I touch so I'm using the OnTouchListener to get the x,y coordinates.
But when I run the code on the emulator the circle is not drawn where I clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //------------------

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRealMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;//480
        int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;//1920

        Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

         canvas = new Canvas(bg);
        RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayoutCells);
        ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));

        ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    float  xf =  event.getRawX();
                    float  yf =  event.getRawY();
                    Log.d("=", String.valueOf(x) + " " + String.valueOf(xf));
                    Paint fillpaint= new Paint();;
                    fillpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    fillpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                    canvas.drawCircle(xf, yf, 5, fillpaint);
                    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 15, fillpaint);
                }
                Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                button.setText("ghj");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's draw in wrong place or not at all?

Comment: xf and yf should be the real touch position, what are you doing with x and y?

Comment: The `MotionEvent#getRaw*()` methods return coordinates based on the whole screen, not the `View`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `event.getRawX()`. The returned value is completly raw and not adjusted to your view. If the canvas is not scaled, use `event.getX()` instead. It makes a difference because of what it returns. getX returns x adjusted to custom views but getRawX is based on the screen which causes inaccuracy.

Comment: If you are using a scaled canvas you have to scale the coordinates as well.

Comment: Are you scaling the canvas?

Comment: What are the x and y used for? where are they initialized?

Comment: i don't think i'm using the scaling. the x,y used them for testing they should be deleted sorry.